# Wizard control does not work

Tags: asp.net, wizard, aspwizard

I'm new to the ASP.NET's Wizard control and couldn't make it work. I guess there is a minor issue in the code that prevent the wizard from displaying. Here is the code snippet that I put inside a server form.

```
<asp:Wizard id="Wizard1" runat="server" >

   <asp:WizardSteps>

    <asp:WizardStep runat="server" id="firstStep" Title="First step">        

     What is your name<asp:TextBox id="txtName" />

    </asp:WizardStep>

    <asp:WizardStep runat="server" AllowReturn="false"  id="lastStep" Title="Last step">

     That's all for today. Good bye.

    </asp:WizardStep>

   </asp:WizardSteps>

  </asp:Wizard>
```

Comment: @hunter there are about 30 tagged ASP.net + Wizard questions on the wizard. A new following must be starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors like WizardSteps, missing runat="server" and some others

try this

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard2" runat="server">
<WizardSteps>
  <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
   What is your name<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
  </asp:WizardStep>
  <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
  That's all for today. Good bye.
  </asp:WizardStep>
</WizardSteps>
```